# HTTP: Status 405: url: 'http://mydashboard/mybi/gateway.php''

Tags: php

Whenever I login on http://mydashboard/mybi/, I am getting the error

> aultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 405: url: 'http://mydashboard/mybi/gateway.php''
>
> Nothing

Whenever I am login I am getting the error.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$webroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$configfile = "$dir/amf_config.ini";

//default zend install directory
$zenddir = $webroot. '/ZendFramework/library';

//Load ini file and locate zend directory
if(file_exists($configfile)) {
    $arr=parse_ini_file($configfile,true);
    if(isset($arr['zend']['webroot'])){
        $webroot = $arr['zend']['webroot'];
        $zenddir = $webroot. '/ZendFramework/library';
    }
    if(isset($arr['zend']['zend_path'])){
        $zenddir = $arr['zend']['zend_path'];
    }
}


// Setup include path
//add zend directory to include path
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.$zenddir);
// Initialize Zend Framework loader
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
// Load configuration
$default_config = new Zend_Config(array("production" => false), true);
$default_config->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini($configfile, 'zendamf'));
$default_config->setReadOnly();
$amf = $default_config->amf;

// Store configuration in the registry
Zend_Registry::set("amf-config", $amf);
// Initialize AMF Server
$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setProduction($amf->production);
if(isset($amf->directories)) {
    $dirs = $amf->directories->toArray();
    foreach($dirs as $dir) {
        // get the first character of the path. 
        // If it does not start with slash then it implies that the path is 
    relative to webroot. Else it will be treated as absolute path
        $length = strlen($dir);
        $firstChar = $dir;
        if($length >= 1)
            $firstChar = $dir[0];

        if($firstChar != "/"){
            // if the directory is ./ path then we add the webroot only.
            if($dir == "./"){               
                $server->addDirectory($webroot);
            }else{
                $tempPath = $webroot . "/" . $dir;
                $server->addDirectory($tempPath);
            }       
        }else{
            $server->addDirectory($dir);            
        }
    }
}
// Initialize introspector for non-production
if(!$amf->production) {
    $server->setClass('Zend_Amf_Adobe_Introspector', '', array("config" => 
    $default_config, "server" => $server));
    $server->setClass('Zend_Amf_Adobe_DbInspector', '', array("config" => 
    $default_config, "server" => $server));
}
// Handle request
echo $server->handle();

// Initialize introspector for non-production if(!$amf->production) { 
$server->setClass('Zend_Amf_Adobe_Introspector', '', array("config" => 
    $default_config, "server" => $server)); $server- 
   >setClass('Zend_Amf_Adobe_DbInspector', '', array("config" => 
    $default_config, "server" => $server)); } // Handle request echo $server- 
   >handle();
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. If the last few lines really look like they do here, then you will get syntax errors. In any case, check your logs.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem?